# Unable to parse date from string using NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am stuck for a while parsing date in string using `NSDateFormatter`

Date in string is in below format

> 1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM

Below is the code I use to parse

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc]init];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM"];
```

This code works with date @"12/31/2011" and format @"MM/dd/yyyy"

Please help

Comment: you only need this : `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];`

Comment: There are lots of similar questions and answers already. You just need to give dateFormat as @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" or HH if your hours is 24 hour format. No need to set styles. parse the date and then set the format if you want to convert the date to some other formats.

Comment: Every several hours, I read a question concerning the date format.  Why don't they just run a search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use my bellow custom method and parse that date into another format...

```
-(NSString *)changeDateFormat:(NSString*)stringDate dateFormat:(NSString*)dateFormat getwithFormat:(NSString *)getwithFormat{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:getwithFormat];

    NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    //NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);
    return convertedString;
}
```

use this method like bellow..

```
 NSString *strSDate = [self changeDateFormat:@"1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM" dateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" getwithFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
 NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",strSDate);
```

Set any Format which you want in `getwithFormat` parameter and set format in `dateFormat` parameter which you have with your Date string...

**OUTPUT IS => Converted String : 01/01/2011**

Comment: @ParasJoshi there is no need to instantiate a new dateFormatter after getting date, you can just change the format that's it :). Edited

Comment: ya i know here if he just add a in that formatter then it will work but i just give this method which used anytime with any format.. its very easy method what you say?? :)

Comment: Yeah it will work as long as there is no issue with the timezone, if the input date string has timeZone it work flawlessly. But if there isn't then there might be issue. Like Server send in UTC and with current setting dateFormatter will assume the dateString is in localTimeZone.

Comment: ya but most off its working well here i also create that type of method but after i assume that this is better for use.. :) thanx..

Comment: I just pointed as creating an instance of NSDateFormatter is always expensive, if there are lots of conversions, many will suggest to make it static or keep it as an instance variable. That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
//First format date from string
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01/01/2011 12:00:00 AM"];

//Set date formatter to specific format
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

//Log the value
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
```