# Converting NSString to NSDate

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdateformatter, datetime-format

I am converting two strings of date and time to `NSDate` but i always get wrong time, but getting correct date, I don't know why xcode is giving wrong log message,I have seem many `NSDate` code but all are not working, this one is working when I changed date format, tell me what to do for time format

```
     NSDate * date;
    //Assume dateString is populated and of format NSString * dateString =@"2011-11-21 11:20";
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString *dateString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", socialEvent.SocialEventsDC_EventDate,socialEvent.SocialEventsDC_EventStartTime];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@",socialEvent.SocialEventsDC_EventDate,socialEvent.SocialEventsDC_EventStartTime);

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a"];
    if (dateString != nil)  {
        date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
//        [date release];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

my log message is

```
2013-04-25 10:45:04.417 BNI UK & Ire[450:5203] 01/20/2015 11:00 PM
2013-04-25 10:45:09.679 BNI UK & Ire[450:5203] 2015-01-20 07:00:00 +0000
```

my time is always 7:00:00 although my time is 11:00, please help me

Comment: You live 4 hours behind GMT., I guess near WestIndies, guaya etc http://timezoneguide.com/time-gmt-4.html

Comment: If this is the case, your time is correct, and that is shown in that way. you need to convert it into string.

Comment: Are you using the simulator? The log always say NOT GMT time. Don't worry about that, it's a log problem, not in your app.

Comment: i have used both simulator and on device but results are same

Comment: but i also get same time when my time is different

Comment: 2013-04-25 10:58:38.787 BNI UK & Ire[495:1303] 04/30/2013 6:00 PM
2013-04-25 10:58:38.792 BNI UK & Ire[495:1303] 2013-04-30 07:00:00 +0000

Comment: when time is 6 it also giving me 7

Comment: @QualityCoder try this answer may you get some idea from that.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162520/unable-to-parse-date-from-string-using-nsdateformatter/16162624#16162624

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code...

```
    NSString * dateString =@"2011-11-21 11:20";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"];
    // [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    NSDate *datTemp = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

    NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:datTemp];
    NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:datTemp];
    NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;
    NSDate* destinationDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:datTemp] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n Destination date is:- %@",destinationDate);
```

Comment: it give me this log message Destination date is: 2013-04-20 00:40:00 +0000
2013-04-29 11:50:22.617 BNI UK & Ire[843:1303] 


 Destination date is: 2015-01-20 12:00:00 +0000

Comment: my time is 8:40 and destination gives me 00:40:00

Comment: here your time is 8:40 and you get 40 then its not correct but its bcoz with differ with timezones.. like EDT. See my blog with Date info and also ooficial docs for NSDate....https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1 and  http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/01/date-formate-info-for-iphone-sdk.html hope it will helpful to you....

Answer (score 1):

try like this ,

```
NSDate *mydate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval secondsInEightHours = 4 * 60 * 60;
NSDate *dateEightHoursAhead = [mydate dateByAddingTimeInterval:secondsInEightHours];
```

Comment: some where else you went wrong otherwise it'l give correct result.

Answer (score 1):

If the dateString is as given below this should work, timezone is assumed be your local timeZone. And log of date will be in UTC

```
NSString *dateString = @"2011-11-21 11:20";

NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];

NSDate * date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code...

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
    [dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    NSDate *myDate = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:@"01/20/2015 11:00 pm"];
    NSLog(@"mydate is :%@",myDate);
    NSLog(@"DATE IS : %@",[dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:myDate]);
```

Note:timeZone depend upon your local timeZone.